# Getting a user object from request.getAttribute method

Tags: java, web

I'm making a java web project, where i need to get a user object, to use a method from my DataMapper.

in my login form i have this code:

```
String execute( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws LoginSampleException {


    String email = request.getParameter( "email" );
    String password = request.getParameter( "password" );

    User user = null;
    try {
        user = LogicFacade.login(email, password);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute( "user", user );
    session.setAttribute( "role", user.getRole() );
    return user.getRole() + "page";
}
```

}

now i need the user object again in another servlet.

can i simply call the the request.getAttribute method to get the same object from the Httpsession?

```
        Order order = new Order(length, height, width, shed, false);

        User user =(User)request.getAttribute("user");


    try {
        DataMapper.createOrder(order, user);
//error handling and code continues
```

Comment: Set :
ses = request.getSession(true);
ses.setAttribute("Name","Value");

And get:
request.getSession(false).getAttribute("name");

Comment: @Amit does this mean the code is correct?

Comment: Your setAttribute code is correct but you should need to change the getAttribute code like below:
request.getSession().getAttribute("user");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you set the user object into HttpSession, then you can get the user object by using below code:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```